# Truncate middle japanese chacracter uilabel ellipsis center line

Tags: ios

I have a issue.
uilabel in cell uicollectionview, i set text for this if text is japanese character or chinese character ellipsis truncate tail have center line position (e.x: Image)

[Image issue center line ellipsis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v705y.png)

some time ellipsis truncate tail have bottom line position ( e.x: Image)

[Image issue bottom line ellipsis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y9W12.png)

Comment: Seems like this is how japanese ellipses are supposed to look. See e.g. https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%AA%E3%83%BC%E3%83%80%E3%83%BC_(%E8%A8%98%E5%8F%B7)

Comment: @Gereon thanks for answer but sometime ellipsis have position bottom line. :(. all uilabel in cell have ellipsis not be same position

Comment: There seem to be a difference between the two samples in terms of characters and perhaps size? Perhaps try to understand what causes the different behavior?